# 413 error in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have such problem:
I set

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 10485760
LimitRequestBody 10485760
```

in httpd.conf

but when I post large portions of text (about 2 mb) via Django admin panel I still get Apache's Error 413. Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the apache error log, it may have more useful information.  Also check to ensure that you restarted the server after making those changes, and check that the server actually accepted those numbers.  Lastly, check to ensure that Django is not returning the error, as it may also have an uplaod file limit.

Answer (score 1):

Double, triple, quadruple check that you're doing a POST, and not a GET.  Packet captures would help.